# Deleting Subscribers from Hidden Triggered Send Managed Lists in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, contactbuilder, subscriber, subscriber-key

I've followed the steps on https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381035&type=1 to be able to create and populate a data extension with Subscribers from the Hidden Triggered Send Managed List.

However, I'm unsure on how to proceed with the instructions provided for deleting the Contact via Contact Builder. The crucial point here is that the back-end Marketing Cloud SubscriberId is different in the Hidden Triggered Send Managed List for the Subscriber I wish to delete vs the main Subscriber record. I therefore only have this Id as a way of isolating the specific record I need to delete (as the SubscriberKey is the same for both records), but there's no way to search via SubscriberId in Contact Builder.

Without affecting the main Subscriber record in All Subscribers, how can I isolate and delete just the record in the Hidden Triggered Send Managed List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to have the Subscriber Id in your data source to perform the contact deletion.

As long as, the data source is a sendable DE and have the "Subscriber key relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key" or the "SubscriberID relates to Subscribers on SubscriberID" then it would be fine.

One note is that the contact deletion needs to be performed in the parent BU, so if you have the triggered send DE in a child BU, you would need to make a copy DE in your parent BU.

Also, it not just only deletes the subscribers in your email channel (All subscribers list) but the contacts in All Contacts list.

Comment: I've now seen the option to delete from the data extension.

Comment: Have you tried the option "Delete contacts from data extensions"? Click the drop down in the trash bin icon will show it

Comment: Glad to know, it's helpful to you @AntonioDePalma :)